# Calcular porcentagem de votos

Tags: php

Olá, tenho um sistema de votação de uma notícia que contém like e deslike.

Porém, gostaria de calcular uma porcentagem dessa notícia, baseada na quantidade de votos, positivos ou negativos. Por ex: quando não tiver nenhum voto seria 100%, ou com 10 positivos também 100%. Como posso fazer isso no php?

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre a conta? Não está claro.

Comment: Eu registro os votos, like e deslikes. Quero fazer um calculo para saber a porcentagem da notícia baseado nesses votos. Ou seja, para dar uma nota a notícia...

Comment: dislike + like = Total.
(Dislike / Total) * 100 = % de dislike.
(Like / Total) * 100 = % de like.
Se puder postar algum trecho de código fica melhor para exemplificar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, acredito que seja isso:

**EDIT:**

Conforme comentario do Bacco, há um risco de divisão por zero que pode ser inibido com um IF. Deste modo:

```
$like = 3;
$dislike = 10;
$total = $like + $dislike;
if($total != 0){
  $porcentagemLike = ($like / $total) * 100;
  $porcentagemDislike = ($dislike / $total) * 100;
} else {
#caso nao tenha like ou dislike, seta like como 100% e dislike como zero;
  $porcentagemLike = 100;
  $porcentagemDislike = 0;

}
```

Comment: Me foi útil em java, valeu!